# Hide schema not accessible for users in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have in my postgres database a schema by client with a specific user. Each user (=client) can access only his schema (and the public schema). He is connected by default on his own schema (with search_path). Great but...
He can see all the schema's name of others clients when he is connected by odbc (on MS Access or Qgis for example). It's not a big problem because he can not see anything in others schemas but I would like (for confidentiality) that he see only schemas he can access (with GRANT role). Is-it possible ?
Thank's